# Wordpress/PHP Get days between two dates and create array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have a `custom-post-type` for Vacationperiods where there are some custom fields of type Datepicker to set start and end date. Now I want to get all the days between these to dates and add them to an array.

```
function get_vacation_dates(){
global $post;

  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('vacationperiods'),
    'post_status' => array('publish'),
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );

  $posts = get_posts($args);
  $vac = [];
  foreach ($posts as $post){

    $vacationTitle = get_field('name', $post->ID);
    $startDate = get_field('vacation_start', $post->ID);
    $endDate = get_field('vacation_end', $post->ID);

    // GET ALL DAYS/DATES
    for ($i=$startDate; $i<=$endDate; $i+=86400) {  
        $days = date('Y-m-d', $i);
    }       

    $duration = dateDiff($startDate, $endDate);

    $vac[] = [
        'name' => $vacationTitle,
        'start' => $startDate,
        'end' => $endDate,
        'duration' => $duration,
        'days' => $days
    ];



  }

  echo json_encode($days);

  die();
}
```

This approach does not work, it gives me `"days: '1970-01-01'"` - but as mentioned before I want to get all days listed as an array, something like "days: `['2018-09-13', '2018-09-14', etc..]`

How can I achieve that?

Comment: convert date into strtotime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`strtotime()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_strtotime.asp) function parses an English textual DateTime into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).

Something like this:

```
$days = array();
    // GET ALL DAYS/DATES
        for ($i=strtotime($startDate); $i<=strtotime($endDate); $i+=86400) {  
            $days[] = date('Y-m-d', $i);
        }
```

Comment: For some reason, this only gives me the endDate as result :-/

Comment: Do you mean last date of loop?

Comment: Yes exactly, the last date of loop

Comment: Actually, `$days` is a variable. it overrides with last value. It should be define an array or as you want.

Comment: Define `$days` as an array `$days = array();`. see updated answer.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks thousand times :-)